# How do I reset ownership on /usr/bin/sudo on centOS?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo

I accidentlly changed ownership of `/usr/bin/sudo` to my current user (i also did this for some other stuff in my `/usr` directory).  I can't change any of them back because I need ownership of `/usr/bin/sudo` to be root to do so.  I do not have root access because I'm on an Amazon EC2 instance running linux.

Here's what I did (foolishly I know):

```
sudo chown -R currentuser.currentuser /usr/
```

I've also hosed a ton of other stuff in the process, but I think it can all be solved if I can reset ownership of `/usr/bin/sudo`

Please help.  I'm brand new to Linux admin and am doing everything from the command line.

EDIT: I used -R in my sudo chown command.

EDIT2: I have most of my data on a separate, mounted EBS, but I'm awful with server admin and it'll probably take me an entire day to setup a new instance.

Comment: You might need to get your instance reset...

Comment: Should be migrated to unix.SE

Comment: That command only changes ownership for `/usr`, not for `/usr/bin/sudo`...

Comment: Is this an instance-store root instance, or an EBS-root instance?

Comment: @bdonlan He must've used `-R` :-/

Comment: @bdonlan Now, please do not learn about the recursive flag.

Comment: I know about -R, my point is his command isn't actually the one he used. Maybe he changed ownership of all of `/`? I don't want to assume once I know the command is wrong :)

Comment: @bdonlan It was foolish for me to assume, but he edited in the meantime so I guess I guessed right :-))

Comment: sorry ... i updated it, and did use -R

Comment: This question should be migrated to serverfault, not closed outright... flagged.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question to multiple sites.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073) sagi's reposted his answer on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/q/290105), so I'm flagging to delete this copy of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no solution that allowed me to fix this problem from within that system with that user.  I could not get root access, and there was no trick to get around the problem.

I had to ditch the server and start anew.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running on an EBS volume? Can you afford to shutdown the instance for a few minutes?

If you do, then you can temporarily stop the current instance, start another instance, mount the EBS volume of the first instance and fix its permissions, then unmount it and re-start the first instance.