# What to do if the owner of /usr/bin/* changes to a non-root?

Tags: linux, centos, sudo, root, chown

It would be the right thing to say that I messed up!

Accidentally, I changed the owner of all files in /usr/bin to 'dev' from 'root'. Now, sudo does not work! If I use sudo with any command, I get -

`sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?`

I cannot use `chown` command to change the owner back to 'root'. This is a major set back!

Because this is a Virtual Machine, I cannot access the Recovery Console. Infact, even the `reboot` command needs the user to have 'root' access.

Experts, please help me in getting control of the OS without having to re-image.

Thanks!

P.S - Possibly a [duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16647/how-do-i-reset-ownership-on-usr-bin-sudo-on-centos?rq=1) but reposting as his solution was to start afresh.

**More info -**

`su - root` always says incorrect password. Unfortunately, the owner of `su` is also 'dev'.

I am able to create a new user using the GUI. It accepted the root password. How do I grant the new user with root access without using visudo.

Comment: Are you able to use `vi` ?

Comment: Yes @Sreeraj, I am able to use `vi`

Comment: If you changed owner of `su`, then you're out of luck. What does `which su` says?

Comment: @siblynx it says /bin/su. The owner of su is also 'dev'

Comment: So not only /usr/bin is affected. If you have no physical access, then it's best to ask someone who has.

Comment: Is there anyway to get this done using gnome? I am able use root password there to create a new user. How do I give that user root privilege without using visudo on terminal, the GUI way!

Comment: What apps you're having root in exactly? Can you browse or create files inside them? Or changing ownership of files with something like "properties" tab?

Comment: Ownership cannot be changed for any file using terminal because sudo does not wok. Any GUI way around it? I was able to user User Manage GUI app using root password.

Comment: There is not GUI around probably because GUIs usually rely on sudo. And if not, then you should have some app or shell running **already** as superuser, which you probably not.

Comment: Have you tried with a chroot? Like booting a live Arch Linux (or whatever distro you prefer) into your virtual machine, and access your system file from there?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand that @JeffreyLebowski.

Comment: @Jeffrey Lebowski OP has no "physical" access to do that. Just curious, do you have root ssh access? Or root is explicitly disabled?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Is it possible to copy the sudo binary from another OS an copy it in my OS to chane the original sudo's ownership?

Comment: Do you own that virtual machine somehow? Is it a VPS or other entity offered to you by a hosting provider? If so, then they should give you access tokens such as root password and ip address of machine. If you do not know, then you're probably not an owner of it.

Comment: No it's not possible because only root can change privileged bits on executables. If anyone would, then system would be completely insecure.

Comment: I see. I do have IP for the VDI which I use to connect. However, I was able to add a new user in User Manager GUI where it accepted the root password.

Comment: Can you add user with 0 uid?

Comment: Nope, it says `uid 0 is already in use`

Comment: That looks silly, every unix system can duplicate users with same uid. Can you change password of root?

Comment: User Manager GUI does not show root as a user. It only shows other users.

Comment: It's best to see someone who will recover your machine from failed state.

Comment: @Swanidhi I meant, can you boot another OS into your virtual machine (e.g. an Arch Linux live USB) and access your original system by [chrooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/change_root) into it?

Comment: @siblynx I'm not 100% sure I understood the situation. Can't he plug an USB key into his computer and boot from it in his virtual system?

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski Yes, he can't. As I understand and interpret his words right -> "Because this is a Virtual Machine, I cannot access the Recovery Console.", I think that what he does access to is only to the shell where the mistake was done. And yes, he can plug a USB key into _his computer_ and boot from it, but it's unrelated to a virtual machine which is hosted somewhere else :-) Or I think there is still too low information to judge by (Recovery Console - what is it?)

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski - Yes, I cannot use a USB drive. I meant the recovery console of CentOS to change/resolve the root issue. I just use an IP address within a VPN to access the VM.
Although, I have requested for reimaging the VM, I'll still keep this question open for a while just to find an alternate solution.

Comment: Your `chown` command (Read `man -a chown`), changed the dozen or so different ownerships to `dev`. It also cleared the `setUID` and `setGID` bits. There is no easily accessible way to recover the lost ownership information,  or reapply the `setUID` and `setGID` bits. Back up your user data (a Live USB and a big disk) and reinstall

Answer (score 1):

Physical security is security.  You have three options:

1. Log in as root, either from the console or by ssh.
2. Boot in single-user mode, which traditionally doesn't need the root password (but might on your system).
3. Mount the disk image from another OS.

Any of these will give you the ability to change the ownership of any file on the disk.  If none of them is an option for you, you're out of luck, but you're also not in control: other things -- that aren't mistakes -- can happen that require console access.

Comment: Incidentally, checking root pw in single user is done in a way that doesn't care about suid binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say anything for sure without spinning up a VM and imitating your situation, but what I'd probably do is, if you can have a file act as external media for your VM, boot up a Live CD/USB distro (Knoppix, or the default archiso, or the Gentoo install CD, or Porteus) and then do something like mounting the filesystem with the broken /usr/bin (perhaps using `cd /; mkdir /backup; cp /mnt/centos/usr/bin /backup`, copying over the binary files you want to save and `chown -hR 0 /backup; chmod 755` them or whatever your chosen privileges for /usr/bin are, then deleting the /usr/bin in ***only*** the broken stuff (if the fs to be fixed was mounted at /mnt/centos, the command to use for the last instruction would be `rm -r /mnt/centos/usr/bin`) then something among the lines of `cp /backup /mnt/centos/usr/bin` And that might work. Don't do this yet though, since I still haven't spun up a VM to test this. If you ***can't*** make a file act as an external bootable medium, then I think you need to reinstall, after making a backup of all files you want to save. I hope this answer serves you well.

Comment: Also, it might be possible to just use the bootable external medium and just `chown -hR /mnt/centos/usr/bin`the thing. Also, is your system one where /bin is linked to /usr/bin (similar to Debian 11 and recent releases of Fedora) or are they different directories?